# Convert UTC datetime to local datetime using java.time

Tags: java, java-time, localdatetime

I have a UTC date-time like this (a String): `2022-11-22T17:15:00`

And a ZoneID like this: `"America/Tijuana"`

Using java.time API, I want to get the actual datetime for that zone, which is: `2022-11-22T09:15:00` (the time is 09:15 instead of 17:15)

- ZonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime() returns: `2022-11-22T17:15`
- ZonedDateTime.toString() returns:
  `2022-11-22T17:15-08:00[America/Tijuana]`

None of the above gives me what I'm looking for.

This is my code:

```
    ZoneId zonaID = ZoneId.of('America/Tijuana');
    CharSequence dateUTC = "2022-11-22T17:15:00";
    LocalDateTime dateTimeL = LocalDateTime.parse(dateUTC);
    ZonedDateTime myZDT = ZonedDateTime.now();
    ZonedDateTime myZDTFinal = myZDT.of(dateTimeL, zonaID);
    System.out.println("using toLocalDateTime: " + myZDTFinal.toLocalDateTime());
    System.out.println("using toString: " + myZDTFinal.toString());
```

I know that this might be a duplicated question but there's so many questions about date-times and I just haven't been able to figure out this.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: `myZDT.of(dateTimeL, zonaID)` is calling a static method as if it's an instance method. I'd strongly avoid doing that - it's really confusing.

Comment: The answers you already got are correct answers. Your main problem was that you assumed that string "2022-11-22T17:15:00" is UTC, but in the string itself there is no such indication. in other words it is a LocalDateTime. If you know that it is meant to be UTC, you first need to create ZonedDateTime from LocalDateTime you have with UTC ZoneId, and than convert it to your zoneID "America/Tijuana"

Comment: I would use `dateTimeL.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZoneSameInstant(zonaID);`. Gives `using toString: 2022-11-22T09:15-08:00[America/Tijuana]`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for mentioning `dateTimeL.atOffset`. My original answer was using `dateTimeL.atZone` with `ZoneOffset.UTC` but I realized that it's more appropriate to get an `OffsetDateTime` if we use `ZoneOffset.UTC` which refers to a `ZoneOffset` rather than a `ZoneId`. Now, I've updated my answer to use your approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be many ways to achieve the result. A simple approach would be

1. Parse the given string into `LocalDateTime`.
2. Convert it into an `OffsetDateTime` at UTC using [`LocalDateTime#atOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atOffset-java.time.ZoneOffset-).
3. Use [`OffsetDateTime#atZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#atZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) to convert the resulting `OffsetDateTime` into a `ZonedDateTime` at `ZoneId.of("America/Tijuana")`.
4. Get `LocalDateTime` out of the resulting `ZonedDateTime` by using  [`ZonedDateTime#toLocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDateTime--).
5. If required, format this `LocalDateTime` into the desired string.

```
LocalDateTime
    .parse("2022-11-22T17:15:00") // Parse the given date-time string into LocalDateTime
    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC) // Convert it into a ZonedDateTime at UTC
    .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Tijuana")) // Convert the result into a ZonedDateTime at another time-zome
    .toLocalDateTime() // Get the LocalDateTime out of the ZonedDateTime
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH))); // If required
```

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldtInTijuana = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-11-22T17:15:00")
                .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Tijuana"))
                .toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldtInTijuana);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = ldtInTijuana.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-22T09:15
2022-11-22T09:15:00
```

Note that [`LocalDateTime#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--) removes second and fraction-of-second values if they are zero. Suppose you want to keep them (**as you have posted in your question**), you can use a `DateTimeFormatter` as shown above.

### An alternate approach:

Alternatively, you can append `Z` at the end of your ISO 8601 formatted date-time string to enable `Instant` to parse it and then convert the `Instant` into a `ZonedDateTime` corresponding to the `ZoneId.of("America/Tijuana")` by using [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-). The symbol, `Z` refers to UTC in a date-time string.

The rest of the steps will remain the same.

**Demo**:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2022-11-22T17:15:00";
        text = text + "Z"; // Z refers to UTC
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(text);
        LocalDateTime ldt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Tijuana")).toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-11-22T09:15
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Arvind Kumar Avinash , I think the alternate approach is better since I already know that the original date is UTC, so it's easier to append a 'Z' to that string. I need to convert hundreds of datetimes for every submit, so I'm looking for the best performance option

Answer (score 7):

You have to convert your date to UTC, then convert the convert this zone to your expected zone using `withZoneSameInstant` like this:

```
ZonedDateTime toUTCZone  = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTimeL, ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime myZDTFinal = toUTCZone.withZoneSameInstant(zonaID);
```

**Output**

```
2022-11-22T09:15-08:00[America/Tijuana]
```

Comment: One small update: `ZoneOffset.UTC` is the more idiomatic way of referring to the UTC ZoneId.